# Is encrypt-and-MAC secure for AES-CTR + UMAC?

Tags: authenticated-encryption, ssh

OpenSSH will (especially in older versions) use AES-CTR plus a MAC in encrypt-and-MAC.  This is not secure in general (meaning that there exist secure ciphers and secure MACs such that using them in encrypt-and-MAC is insecure).

However, as I understand it AES-CTR + MAC as used in SSH *is* secure, at least for the MAC choices actually in use, because:

1. The MACs used (HMAC and UMAC/VMAC + encrypt the MAC tag) are
   *privacy-preserving*: the MAC tag does not leak any information about
   the plaintext, at least for one who does not know the MAC key.  In the
   case of HMAC, I believe that this follows from HMAC being a strong PRF;
   in the case of UMAC/VMAC, the security of the MAC depends entirely on
   encrypting the MAC before transmission, and the encryption of the MAC
   also ensures that no information about the plaintext is leaked.
2. No encoding is done between encryption and authentication.  The data
   that is encrypted and the data that is authenticated are one and the
   same.
3. The cipher in question uses CTR mode – in other words, it is a stream
   cipher.  Thus, any change to the ciphertext will cause a 1-to-1 change
   in the plaintext – integrity of plaintext thus implies integrity of
   ciphertexts.

My conclusion is that these cipher suites are actually secure, due to the specifics of the protocol.

Is my reasoning correct?  More importantly, is my *conclusion* correct?  I am not a cryptographer and have zero trust that I did not make a foolish error.

Comment: Why is this encrypt-and-MAC "generally not secure"? Any source/basis for saying that?

Comment: @axapaxa Have you seen the [canonical Q about combining macs and encryption](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/29554) here on the site? If there's an answer to your question, you should find it there.

Comment: @EllaRose I actually checked before saying that. There is nothing about encrypt-and-MAC being broken, it simply has less resistance against cipher/hash breakage (and AES isn't broken). There is nothing about it "being generally insecure", but it isn't recommended in new systems (just like for example 3DES). So still no source/basis for that.

Comment: In fact, I would venture that _most_ MACs are such that _regardless of the encryption scheme_, using the MAC "in encrypt-and-MAC is insecure" (due to revealing, when encryptions are of the same message, with no false-negatives and a false-positive rate that is bounded above by their forgeability). ​ For that reason: ​ ​ ​ Are you sure they're really expected to be privacy-preserving _in the sense you describe_, rather than just satisfying the usual definition of PP-MAC, which allows them to leak message equality? ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Didn't think of message equality.  MACs based on encrypting the output of a universal hash with a stream cipher are immune to that though.  The attack is also foiled for any PP-MAC if the authenticated data includes a message number (which I believe it does in the case of SSH).

Comment: Do the message-encryption and uhash-encryption bits come from (different positions in) the same stream or from (computationally-independent) separate streams? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Don't know, but it shouldn't matter — an adversary should not be able to distinguish them.

Comment: How universal is the hash family? ​ (When just one stream is used, I can make security fail at $\hspace{.57 in}$ the cost of reducing universally by at most double the probability of predicting a hash output.) $\hspace{.47 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer How can you make that happen, for a non-contrived hash?

Comment: I don't see any way of doing it with a non-contrived hash. ​ ​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encrypt-and-MAC does not preserve confidentiality because two encryptions of the same message will have the same mac tag, revealing the fact that the messages are equal.

Ssh includes a counter in the data the mac tag is computed over, so it never computes the mac tag for the same message twice (even if identical data is transmitted twice), so this particular weakness is not an issue.

This is not an endorsement of encrypt-and-MAC, however. **Do not use it.**

(If you have a strange MAC, encrypt-and-MAC can leak even more than equality, but few reasonable MACs are strange.)

Comment: Yes, if the mac is computed over the message, and not the (randomized) ciphertext.

Comment: Have you looked at http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac?noredirect=1&lq=1 ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was confused with Encrypt-then-MAC

Comment: And for the universal-hashing based MACs, the encryption of the MAC means that there is no leak.

Comment: @Demi I don't really understand your comment. If you have a deterministic MAC, E&M leaks message equality. If you have a randomised MAC, it may not leak anything, but these are rare. If you have a stateful MAC, it may not leak anything, but these are rare. If you do not use plain E&M, but some other construction, it may not leak anything.

Comment: @K.G. Typical MACs based on universal hashing are stateful, since they use a stream cipher to encrypt the hash output.  As a result, no information is leaked.

Comment: @Demi I did not know typical universal hash-based MACs were stateful. Examples?

Comment: @K.G. Consider Poly1305-AES.  It computes an almost-universal hash of the message, and then XORs it with a nonce encrypted using AES.  The nonce must not be used more than once – if it is, all security is lost.  If the nonce is used only once, however, the security reduces to that of AES, and no information about the message leaks through to the MAC.

Comment: @Demi An algorithm isn't stateful just because it uses a nonce.